# Insert mode: make C-a insert previously inserted text

Tags: key-bindings, evil

In Vim, `Ctrl-A` can be used in Insert-mode to [insert previously inserted text](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ins-special-keys), much as the "dot" (`.`) command can be used in Normal-mode. For context and a demonstration, watch from [~2m25s - 5m08s](https://youtu.be/3TX3kV3TICU?t=2m25s) in George Brocklehurst's ThoughtBot talk, "Let Vim Do the Typing", or read the excerpt I've transcribed below.

> There is a special register
>   called "dot". The "dot" register contains whatever the last text you
>   inserted was, the last time you were in Insert-mode. The last time
>   I was in Insert-mode, I inserted "Hello<space>world<newline>", so if I
>   go back into Insert-mode and I hit `Ctrl-R`, and then I hit `.`, I
>   reinsert that entire thing. **But even cooler, if I just hit `Ctrl-A`,
>   Vim just does that for me.**

**My question is: how can I obtain this functionality in Evil mode?**

With the default settings, entering `C-a` while in the Insert state of Evil mode just moves my cursor to the beginning of the line.

I tried adding

```el
(define-key evil-insert-state-map "\C-a" 'evil-repeat)
```

to my .emacs file after the call to Evil, but this does not behave quite as expected: on the first invocation after entering the Insert state, it inserts whatever character was previously used to enter the Insert state (e.g. `i` or `I` or `o` or suchlike), and then inserts the expected text. On subsequent invocations, it does not appear to do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`evil-repeat` does something else, it repeats the last *command*, not
insertion.  Here's an approach actually going for what you've
described `C-a` to do.

```
(defun my-evil-paste-last-insertion ()
  (interactive)
  (evil-paste-from-register ?.))

(eval-after-load 'evil-maps
  '(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-a") 'my-evil-paste-last-insertion))
```

edit: [It's part of Evil now](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/commits/ee2a750b7381)!

Comment: Yes, and thank you :) Ticket now [open](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issues/555).

Comment: @wasamasa: thanks for getting it into Evil!